# Removing values, stored in character vector, from a list

Tags: r, list, vector

I want to remove certain values from a list to create a refined list. I have all of the values I want to remove stored in a character vector named remove. The values in remove correspond to the first column of the list. I've run the following code:

```
refined_list = list
for (i in length(list)){
  if (refined_list[i,1] %in% remove){
  refined_list = refined_list[-i,]
}
  else{
    refined_list = refined_list
}
}
```

only the initialization of refined list seems to register. No errors, but refined_list is identical to list. It's a mystery to me

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Perhaps you can make this question reproducible by providing a subset of your list, and your desired output. Also, list is a poor name for a list.

Comment: Just use `lst[!lst[,1] %in% remove,,drop=FALSE]` assuming that `lst` is a `data.frame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're actually talking about lists, since a list cannot be subset as you are proposing (i.e. `list[, 1]`). But if you're looking for a solution for a `data.frame`, here's one:

```
# Set up some test data
dd <- data.frame(letters = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
remove <- letters[c(1, 4, 6)]

# Shed values that are in remove
dd[!(dd[, 1] %in% remove), 1, drop = FALSE]

#> "b" "c" "e" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```